# pyre2 is slower than built-in re module?

Tags: python, cython, re2

When using `pyre2` (https://github.com/axiak/pyre2), I encountered a performance problem (matching time).

I have three programs:

1. pure Python using built-in re module: https://gist.github.com/1873402
2. Python using Pyre2: https://gist.github.com/1873402. (Most part of the code is the same as no.1 program. Except when using built-in re, it will decode utf-8 string to unicode, which is NOT necessary when using pyre2)
3. C/C++ using re2: https://gist.github.com/1873417

I measured two time: regex pre-compile time and matching time.

- no.1 program: 1.65s 1.25s
- no.2 program: 0.04s 1.8s
- no.3 program: 0.02s 0.8s

They all feed by the same regex and input. (All regexes are supported by `re2`)

Then I followed the documentation about profiling in Cython. Got the following result:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   652884   16.477    0.000   25.349    0.000 re2.pyx:394(_search)
     9479    6.059    0.001   41.806    0.004 export_plain.py:60(match)
   652884    4.243    0.000   33.602    0.000 {method 'search' of 're2.Pattern' objects}
   652884    4.010    0.000   29.359    0.000 re2.pyx:442(search)
   652884    3.056    0.000    3.056    0.000 re2.pyx:114(__init__)
   652953    2.145    0.000    2.145    0.000 {isinstance}
   652884    2.002    0.000    2.002    0.000 re2.pyx:123(__dealloc__)
   652953    1.911    0.000    1.911    0.000 re2.pyx:75(unicode_to_bytestring)
   652953    1.902    0.000    1.902    0.000 re2.pyx:86(pystring_to_bytestring)
        1    0.330    0.330   42.492   42.492 export_plain.py:98(export_fname)
     9479    0.173    0.000    0.173    0.000 {built-in method sub}
    10000    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
     8967    0.063    0.000    0.099    0.000 re2.pyx:801(get)
    10069    0.061    0.000    0.061    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
       69    0.043    0.001    0.146    0.002 re2.pyx:806(prepare_pattern)
     9036    0.038    0.000    0.038    0.000 re2.pyx:788(__next)
       69    0.022    0.000    0.169    0.002 re2.pyx:905(_compile)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.177    0.177 export_plain.py:36(load)
       69    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 re2.pyx:784(__init__)
       69    0.001    0.000    0.170    0.002 re2.pyx:763(compile)
       38    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
       69    0.001    0.000    0.171    0.002 {re2.compile}
        1    0.001    0.001   42.669   42.669 export_plain.py:160(main)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
       69    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 genericpath.py:38(isdir)
        1    0.000    0.000   42.669   42.669 export_plain.py:153(run_re2_test)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.stat}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:59(join)
        1    0.000    0.000   42.670   42.670 :1()
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'unicode' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rfind' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:109(basename)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:117(dirname)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stat.py:40(S_ISDIR)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stat.py:24(S_IFMT)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__enter__' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

It looks like that the `_search` function (re2.pyx:393) take up too much time. 
But I don't how can be so different between this and the pure C version.

PS:
Pyre2 revision : commit `543f228`

re2 revision : changeset: `79:0c439a6bd795`

---

I guess the actual `Match` function (re2.pyx:424) cost most of the time in this function.

Then I refactor Match function to a cdef function `_my_match` so that I can see it in profile result, also refactor `StringPiece` allocation to cdef function `_alloc_sp`. (Modification detail: https://gist.github.com/1873993) Re-profile it, then get:

```
Mon Feb 20 20:52:47 2012    Profile.prof

         3975043 function calls in 28.265 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   652884   10.060    0.000   20.230    0.000 re2.pyx:452(search)
   652884    4.131    0.000   28.201    0.000 {method 'search' of 're2.Pattern' objects}
   652884    3.647    0.000    3.647    0.000 re2.pyx:394(_my_match)
     9479    3.037    0.000   31.238    0.003 export_plain.py:62(match)
   652884    2.901    0.000    2.901    0.000 re2.pyx:443(_alloc_sp)
   652953    1.814    0.000    1.814    0.000 re2.pyx:86(pystring_to_bytestring)
   652953    1.808    0.000    1.808    0.000 re2.pyx:75(unicode_to_bytestring)
        1    0.332    0.332   31.926   31.926 export_plain.py:96(export_fname)
     9479    0.169    0.000    0.169    0.000 {built-in method sub}
    10000    0.122    0.000    0.122    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
     8967    0.065    0.000    0.099    0.000 re2.pyx:849(get)
    10069    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
       69    0.042    0.001    0.142    0.002 re2.pyx:854(prepare_pattern)
     9036    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 re2.pyx:836(__next)
       69    0.023    0.000    0.166    0.002 re2.pyx:953(_compile)
        1    0.003    0.003   32.103   32.103 export_plain.py:158(main)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.174    0.174 export_plain.py:36(load)
       69    0.002    0.000    0.168    0.002 re2.pyx:811(compile)
       38    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
       69    0.001    0.000    0.169    0.002 {re2.compile}
       69    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 re2.pyx:832(__init__)
        1    0.001    0.001   32.104   32.104 export_plain.py:151(run_re2_test)
        1    0.000    0.000   32.105   32.105 :1()
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
       69    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
       69    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'unicode' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:59(join)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.stat}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 genericpath.py:38(isdir)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:109(basename)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rfind' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:117(dirname)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stat.py:40(S_ISDIR)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__enter__' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 stat.py:24(S_IFMT)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

But `search` still take up so much time (10.060 in tottime).

Anyone can figure out what's the problem?

Comment: Why would you expect pyre to be faster than the built-in module? Cython-generated code is not as fast as hand-written C code (which is the nature of compiled code).

Comment: Because pure re2 is much faster than built-in re module. So I think I can take advantage from that. But pyre2 is slower. At first, I guess is due to the conversion between Python String and C string. Then the profile result didn't support this guess. So I can't figure out why. A not so slow string conversion between C <-> Python  + C++ Module = slow?

Answer (score 7):

Well, it depends... pyre2 is asymptotically faster, but not necessarily faster for **every** specific regex. The reason is that re2 generates a NFA and walks on all active states simultaneously. re (if I am correct) tries only one path in the NFA at a time and if it fails, it backtracks and tries a different one. This means re can do all sorts of fancy stuff like lookaheads etc because it always remembers the path that is matching the given string, while re2 only remembers the current active states. This means that re2 will tell you if the string matches the regex or not, but it is not able to do all the fancy computations you can do with groups using re. As a consequence pyre2 has linear asymptotic time complexity (at the cost of not supporting some of the syntax of the built-in re), while re has exponential asymptotic complexity. However that doesn't mean that for basic simple regexes pyre2 has to perform better.

One more thing to keep in mind:

Did you download pyre2 from the [facebook repository](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2/) or from the [python package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/)?
If you downloaded from the python package index, it will fallback to the built-in re library if it cannot handle the given regex (so I suppose there might be some small overhead there) - in any case if you are matching against regexes that pyre2 doesn't support, it will fall back to re and at least **not** perform any better.

So without seeing your regexes it is hard to say, but my guess is re2 is being slower for 1 of the following reasons:

- either your regexes and strings you're matching against them are very simple (in which case there is no advantage of using re2)
- or you downloaded pyre2 from pypi and you are capturing groups and using lookaheads, which re2 doesn't support and it is falling back to re)

Since you managed to compile the same regexes in the C re2 library, I would guess it's the first reason, not the second.